# How to know correct Weka class options?

Tags: weka

Regard class [`weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html)

Javadoc says it has 2 options, which are expressed as command line parameters:

```
 -M
  treat missing values as a seperate value.

 -B
  just binarize numeric attributes instead 
  of properly discretizing them.
```

While from Weka GUI it says it has 3 options with symbolic names:

```
OPTIONS
missingMerge -- Distribute counts for missing values. Counts are distributed across other values in proportion to their frequency. Otherwise, missing is treated as a separate value.

binarizeNumericAttributes -- Just binarize numeric attributes instead of properly discretizing them.

doNotCheckCapabilities -- If set, evaluator capabilities are not checked before evaluator is built (Use with caution to reduce runtime).
```

[image]

Which option set is correct and how to know correspondence?

Answer (score 0):

There is not just one correct settings. It depends on the dataset and how you wish to apply your attribute selection. The values in the GUI are default ones and of course it is not guaranteed that they are the correct settings.

In case you mean how to check the options, as you can see in the javadoc, the options in the GUI are fields of the class, not just symbolic names; they have getters and setters. You can set them via setOptions() method or via setters however you wish and if you'd like to know their values, you can get them via getters if we mention using Weka API.